# (C#) Google Firebase HTTP post request to read/write data, returned 405 : Method not allowed.

Tags: c#, database, http, firebase, real-time

I am looking to modify the Firebase realtime database from my web-app using an HTTP post request.

I have written the post request, but it seems to return a 405 error.  Any good way around this?

Code below

```
  var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("*DatabaseURL*");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json2 = "{\"user\":\"test\"," +
                          "\"password\":\"bla\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json2);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a custom SDK called FirebaseDatabase. Found here.

https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet